# How to force two decimal places to the right using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ programming. I want to know how I can input any numbers such as 1256 or 2523 and have the output read as 12.56 or 25.23?

Basically what I want is for the last two digits to appear on the right side of the decimal.

Comment: Assign them to a double variable and divided by 100?

Answer (score 5):

```
float value = input / 100.0f;

// C way
printf("%.2f\n", value);

// C++ way
cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << value << endl;
```